# IONIC 6 Build Issue Execution failed for task ':capacitor-splash-screen:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > error: invalid source release: 17

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am new to IONIC and trying to add splash screen and logo. `IONIC Build android` works fine but when I try to build project in android studio I am getting following error

```
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-splash-screen:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> error: invalid source release: 17
```

I am using capacitor to build the project

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an issue with your `"@capacitor/splash-screen"` version in your `package.json`.

Try using an older version.

It could also be related to other capacitor packages, for me it showed up when I used a higher version of `"@capgo/capacitor-updater"`.

I changed it to: `"@capgo/capacitor-updater": "^4.17.46"`,
and it works.

So to summarise my current package.json looks like this:

```
...
"@capacitor/splash-screen": "^4.2.0",
"@capgo/capacitor-updater": "^4.17.46",
...
```